# How to use Count function in Conditional Split Transformation in SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

Can someone help me here with the SSIS Conditional Split Transformation. I want to do a `Count(Column)`. The requirement is ;

> "If the record count exceed 100 records, then move to one output, else move to another output".

I am trying to use this, but not able to get it done.

```
COUNT(FirstName1) > = 100
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the use of COUNT(*) OVER() window function. Change your source query to return the no of rows from the result set and use that field in the conditional split.

> SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(FirstName) OVER() AS NoOfRows FROM TableName

And now in the Conditional split add these conditions

> Outputname: **LessThan100**  Condition: **NoOfRows < 100** 
>   Outputname: **MoreThan100**  Condition: **NoOfRows > 100**